# Who is this Superheroine?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-vs-teen-titans

I was watching [Justice League vs. Teen Titans](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5091548/) today. 
At the end, there is this female superheroine (probably)
[image: Unknown Superheroine]

She has the ability to fly or use that 'thing' under her feet to fly. 

She can be seen here (encircled).

[image: She is coming towards Teen Titans tower]

Also, she was coming towards Teen Titans' tower.

Please help me identify her.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### The character is commonly known as [Terra](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Tara_Markov_%28New_Earth%29) and she was created by Marv Wolfman and George Perez, appearing in New Teen Titans #26 (1982).

In the comic canon her name was Tara Markov. She is best remembered as a Modern Age Teen Titan whose power included terrakinesis, a form of limited telekinesis centered around the movement of mass quantities of Earth.

Her control of the Earth was so powerful she could use her abilities to lift herself and in essence fly as long as she could manipulate the material. She could also shape the material creating hands or barriers. She was very skilled in the use of her powers.

In the comics Terra was a spy sent to infiltrate the Teen Titans to destabilize the group for Slade Wilson. It was implied that Tara operations as a mercenary drove her insane over time.

Her brother, Geo-Force also had similar powers and at one point considered murdering Slade Wilson, holding him complicit for her madness.

The character has appeared in Young Justice, Teen Titans and Teen Titan's Go series in variations on her original costume. Despite her criminal background the character enjoys a modest bit of fame outside of the comics which is rare for a character who started her career as a criminal.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Courtesy of the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_vs._Teen_Titans):

> In a mid-credits scene, Terra is seen approaching Titans Tower.

That said, anyone can edit the Wiki. Points towards it, she's an important part of the Teen Titans mythos, she has long blonde hair, and that shade of orange shows up up in her original costume, as does the mask style:

[image: Cover of The Judas Contract showing Terra with crude hand-drawn circle]

The darker outfit may be a tribute to the animated Teen Titans cartoon:

[image: Terra from the Teen Titans cartoon]

She [is known for flying on a rock platform too](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/terra/4005-5307/).

> Terra has the ability of geokinesis, exhibiting psychokinetic control over the earth and minerals. While she can control massive amounts of earth and rock, shaping it to her will, she has also revealed an incredible amount of fine control, making artistic shapes, or even transmuting raw materials into different crystalline forms. Her primary forms of mobility include **flying on a rock platform** or extremely quick tunneling.

Answer (score 1):

The character that you are looking for is a girl named Terra. She has the ability to control the earth around her which is called terrakinesis (hence the name). That thing she was floating on (at the end of Justice League v. Teen Titans) was a huge piece of rock.